# I have trouble with npm run dev & cross-env. Laravel 8

Tags: npm, node-modules, cross-env

Error after run npm run dev :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxIDy.png)

package.json config:

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "npm run development",
        "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
        "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
        "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --disable-host-check --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
        "prod": "npm run production",
        "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.0"
    }
}
```

I have node version 14.13.1 and npm version 6.14.8
How resolving it's? Thanks!

Comment: Please don't use screenshot to describe the error you're getting :)

Comment: Denied pin my file here :(

Comment: nice, a pinned file to post